# Can a Linear Combination be Linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Definition of a linear combination:

A vector **v** is a linear combination of vectors
 {**v1**, **v2**, ... , **vk**} 
if there are scalars c1, c2, ... , ck such that

**v** = c1**v1** + c2**v2** + ... + ck**vk**

Definition of linearly dependent:

A set of vectors  {**v1**, **v2**, ... , **vk**}  is linearly dependent if there are scalars c1, c2, ... ,ck with at least one not being zero such that

c1**v1** + c2**v2** + ... + ck**vk** = **0**

In effect my question could also be viewed as: can the **v** from the definition of linear combinations be equal to the 0 vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the literal question in the title

> Can a Linear Combination be Linearly dependent?

Is "no", because a "linear combination (of a list of vectors)" is a *vector* while the "linear independence (of a list of vectors)" is a *property* (so either true of false).

You can say that a list of vectors is linearly independent just when the only linear combination that's the $0$ vector is the obvious one with all $0$ coefficients.